# Running into errors while running my junit tests on jenkins build

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, mockito, jersey

The current workflow is as follows: there is a quality gate that my java service (jersey) has to pass before the built docker image can be deployed anywhere (through jenkins). This quality gate includes minimum test coverage. My tests are able to run and pass on my local IDE (Intellij Idea), but when building in jenkins, I get the following errors when the tests are being run:

```
test1: javax.el.ELUtil.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;
test2: Could not initialize class "classBeingTested"
```

I have added a config file (run.poperties), a log config file (log42j) in the test folder, and I know they are functioning as expected because not all of my tests are failing with these errors. For the first error, I've added the following extra dependencies to my pom file (based on this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126690/nosuchmethoderror-during-validator-test-javax-el-3-0-0)):

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.5</version>
 </dependency>
```

But no good. Still facing the error. The second error about not being able to initialise the class, I have absolutely no idea why that is showing up, but I also understand that that can be very specific to my project structure. Any help with either of the errors would be so so helpful. Even a reasonable method to recreate this on my local will be very helpful, because right now, I have no idea where these errors are originating from.

PS: I'm primarily a python developer, so java is not my strong suit. I apologize in advance if my question does not contain the right info. Please let me know and I will add other relevant details if needed

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by some underlying conflict with javax dependency. Posting my final dependency list here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```